# Turning on SEO-Friendly URLs on Joomla makes all navigation show home page

Tags: url, joomla, seo

Here is the site I'm working on: http://demo1.omnihealthtech.com/

If you try navigating with the 'Quick Links' menu, all pages show only the Home page, even though the URL is different. This only happens when I turn SEO-Friendly URLs on.

I've already got my host to do this http://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs , but the problem is still occurring.

Other info:
- This site is running on the 'Gavick Startup' template.
- I have another site running on the 'Gavick Boutique' template, but that has no problems with SEO-Friendly URLs.

Very puzzled by what's going on. I've done a lot of Googling but nothing comes up :\ Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found the problem.

The Gavick theme had plugins called "System - GK Cache" and "System - GK Extended Cache". The Extended Cache was meant as an alternative caching system. Turning both on at the same probably causes a conflict resulting in the problem above. Simply disabling the Extended Cache puts everything back to normal.